# CSS for Chrome style tabs component

Tags: css, vue.js

There is a good Vue3 component for Chrome-style tabs [right here](https://github.com/viewweiwu/vue3-tabs-chrome). I needed to refine the functionality. I studied the source code. The component works based on operations with Dom elements. I tried to simplify the component by taking only the styling from it, and make the functionality within the usual Vue approach.
Unfortunately, as a result of my attempt, the appearance of the component is far from what I wanted. Although it seemed to be almost a complete copy of the original. And my knowledge of css is, alas, clearly not enough.
Can anyone point out any errors? Here's the sample code. If successful, I think it might be useful to others as well. [code link](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export interface Tab {
  label: string
  key: string
  favicon: string
}

const tabs = [
  { label: 'google', key: 'google', favicon: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/google' },
  { label: 'facebook', key: 'facebook', favicon: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/facebook' }
]

const tabWidth = ref<number>(350)

// const calcTabWidth = () => {
// const minWidth = 40
// const maxWidth = 245
// const gap = 7
//   const { $content } = $refs
//   const afterWidth = $refs.$after?.getBoundingClientRect().width || 0
//   if (!$content) return Math.max(maxWidth, minWidth)
//   const contentWidth: number = $content.clientWidth - gap * 3 - afterWidth
//   let width: number = contentWidth / tabs.value.length
//   width += gap * 2
//   if (width > maxWidth) width = maxWidth
//   if (width < minWidth) width = minWidth
//   tabWidth.value = width
// }

onMounted(() => {
  // calcTabWidth()
})

const indexActiveTab = ref(0)

const gap = '7px'
const speed = '150ms'
</script>

<template>
  {{ indexActiveTab }}
  <div class="vue3-tabs-chrome">
    <div class="tabs-content">
      <div
        class="tabs-item"
        v-for="(tab, idx) in tabs"
        :class="{ active: idx === indexActiveTab }"
        :key="tab.key"
        :style="{ width: tabWidth + 'px' }"
      >
        <div class="tabs-background">
          <div class="tabs-background-divider"></div>
          <div class="tabs-background-content"></div>
          <svg class="tabs-background-before" width="7" height="7">
            <path d="M 0 7 A 7 7 0 0 0 7 0 L 7 7 Z"></path>
          </svg>
          <svg class="tabs-background-after" width="7" height="7">
            <path d="M 0 0 A 7 7 0 0 0 7 7 L 0 7 Z"></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-close">
          <svg class="tabs-close-icon" width="16" height="16" stroke="#595959">
            <path d="M 4 4 L 12 12 M 12 4 L 4 12"></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-main" @click="indexActiveTab = idx">
          <span class="tabs-favicon">
            <img class="img" :src="tab.favicon" alt="" />
          </span>
          <span class="tabs-label" :class="{ 'no-close': false, 'no-icon': !tab.favicon }">
            <template>{{ tab.label }}</template>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.vue3-tabs-chrome {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #dee1e6;
  /* position: relative; */
}
.tabs-content {
  height: 34px;
  /* position: relative; */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.tabs-item {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* position: absolute; */

  &:hover {
    z-index: 1;

    .tabs-background-divider {
      display: none;
    }

    .tabs-background-content {
      background-color: #f2f3f5;
    }

    .tabs-background-before,
    .tabs-background-after {
      fill: #f2f3f5;
    }
  }

  &.active {
    z-index: 2;

    .tabs-close {
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    .tabs-background-divider {
      display: none;
    }

    .tabs-background-content {
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    .tabs-background-before,
    .tabs-background-after {
      fill: #fff;
    }
  }

  &:first-of-type {
    .tabs-background-divider::before {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

.tabs-main {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 v-bind(gap) * 2;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  transition: v-bind(speed);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* position: absolute; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs-close {
  top: 50%;
  right: v-bind(gap) * 2;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* position: absolute; */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.tabs-close-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;

  &:hover {
    stroke: #000;
    background-color: #e8eaed;
  }
}

.tabs-favicon {
  height: 16px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;

  .img {
    /* height: 100%; */
    max-width: 15px;
    max-height: 15px;
  }
}

.tabs-label {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* position: relative; */

  &.no-close {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  &.no-icon {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.tabs-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 v-bind(gap) - 1px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs-background-divider {
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 14px);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 7px;
  /* position: absolute; */

  &::before {
    content: '';
    top: 20%;
    right: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: #81878c;
    /* position: absolute; */
  }

  &::after {
    content: '';
    top: 20%;
    left: calc(100% - 1px);
    width: 1px;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: #81878c;
    /* position: absolute; */
  }
}

.tabs-background-content {
  height: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  transition: v-bind(speed);
}

.tabs-background-before,
.tabs-background-after {
  bottom: -1px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  fill: transparent;
  transition: v-bind(speed);
}

.tabs-background-before {
  left: -1px;
}

.tabs-background-after {
  right: -1px;
}

@keyframes tab-show {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: hello, you should post your codes (not links) and probably give a try to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted a project on [Github](https://github.com/vorron/vue-chrome-tabs), where the tabs look more or less like the original.
The styles section looks like this:

```
<style scoped>
.tabs-chrome {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #dee1e6;
}
.tabs {
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  transition: 150ms;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 2.5in;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;

  &:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 8px;
  }

  &:first-of-type::before {
    display: none;
  }

  &:last-of-type::after {
    background-color: #81878c;
    bottom: 25%;
    content: '';
    height: 60%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 1px;
  }

  &:hover {
    background-color: #f2f3f5;
    z-index: 3;
    & + .tab::before {
      display: none;
    }
    &::before {
      display: none;
    }
    &::after {
      display: none;
    }
    & .tabs-background-before {
      fill: #f2f3f5;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    & .tabs-background-after {
      fill: #f2f3f5;
      z-index: 3;
    }
  }
  &.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 5;
    & + .tab::before {
      display: none;
    }
    &::before {
      display: none;
    }
    &::before {
      display: none;
    }
    &::after {
      display: none;
    }
    & .tabs-background-before {
      fill: #fff;
      z-index: 5;
    }
    & .tabs-background-after {
      fill: #fff;
      z-index: 5;
    }
  }
}

.tab::before {
  background-color: #81878c;
  bottom: 25%;
  content: '';
  height: 60%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 1px;
}

.img {
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.label {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.close {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tabs-close-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;

  &:hover {
    stroke: #000;
    background-color: #e8eaed;
  }
}

.tabs-background-before,
.tabs-background-after {
  bottom: -0px;
  position: absolute;
  fill: transparent;
  transition: v-bind(speed);
}

.tabs-background-before {
  left: -7px;
}

.tabs-background-after {
  right: -7px;
}

@keyframes tab-show {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
</style>
```